# How to filter through a collection picklist in flow, just to get the desired value?

Tags: visual-workflow, loop

My collection picklist variable at the end may look like,
*(New,New,Open,Prospecting,Propecting,New,Nurture, Demo Booked, Opt-out, Opt-out)*

I need to get just one value from these which is the highest in order i.e. **New<Open<Protesting<Nurture<Demo Booked<Opt-Out**.

How do I do that in a flow? Is it by multiple assignments in the loop or we do that outside the loop of a flow?

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess my answer to this would be to check with the decision element from the top value option to least value option. I do not know if its exactly the answer as my flow has been taking default path instead taking one of the outcomes of 6 outcomes.

Comment: "Open"
Outcome conditions

Does Require Record Changed to meet criteria: true
{!contactsStageText} ([Open]) Contains Open
Skipped this outcome because its conditions weren't met:

Answer (score 0):

At the point of asking question, I was unware of the fact that Picklist values can be collected in single text variable using Add function in the loop.

Lest say that the single text variable is `Textsinglevar` where all the picklist values gets collected using loop and `textvarStage` (New/open/Prospecting/....) .

Later  `Textsinglevar` (New,New,Open,Prospecting,Propecting,New,Nurture, Demo Booked, Opt-out, Opt-out) is used in decision element to see if it `Contanis` first the highest priority stage and another decision branch to see if the second highest priority is collected in  `Textsinglevar` and so on. So the decision element first checks the highest priority stage from first branch and second branch will check second highest priority stage and so on. `Textsinglevar` should be text to use with contain or else it has to be picklist to compare with picklist variable on value, which can be done using single picklist and assigning required value to it.